# How can I share a variable amongst a jQuery event map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, events, dry

Given the following jQuery `.on()` event map:

```
$('header').on({
  mouseenter: function(e) {},
  mouseleave: function(e) {},
}, 'li');
```

How can I share a `var $this = $(this)` variable between both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to keep it DRY?

**EDIT**:

To be clearer, if I want to apply the logic to each event in the event map, let's say:

```
mouseenter: function(e) {
  // Grabs the list element.
  var $this = $(this);

  // Gets the sub-menu of the active menu item, if there is one.
  var $subMenu = $this.find('.main-menu__sub-menu').first();

  if ($subMenu.length) {
    // Do something...
  }
},
mouseleave: function(e) {
  // Perform the same checks, and get the same variables as above...
},
click: function(e) {
  // Again, perform the same checks and grab the same variables as above...
}
```

I obviously don't want to repeat my logic, but I require getting the `li` element that's firing the event, which will be the same for all events within the event map... Hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: If you mean that you want the `header` element to be shared between the event handlers via `this`, then it already will be. That's how jQuery works. If that's not what you mean, please clarify your question to be clear about exactly what behaviour you want to create.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve? you could place a variable in the global scope under `window`, but it all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Also, you probably _want_ to separate your `$(this)`s from one another, so that you can let jQuery handle what `this` means within each handler. Any attempt to reuse/cache the value of `$(this)` in a context other than the currently running event handler will probably lead to a handler running against an element you don't want to run it against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your expanded description, you could go for something like this:

```
function getSubmenu(li) {
    // Grabs the list element.
    var $li = $(li);

    // Gets the sub-menu of the active menu item, if there is one.
    var $subMenu = $li.find('.main-menu__sub-menu').first();
    return $subMenu;
}

$('header').on({
    mouseleave: function(e) {
        var $subMenu = getSubmenu(this)
        // do some stuff...
    },
    click: function(e) {
        var $subMenu = getSubmenu(this)
        // do some other stuff...
    }
 }, 'li');
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to make a separate function, or pollute to windows variable list, but I guess there's no way around it. Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript lacks macros (at the moment), so functions become the basic building blocks for reusability. If you want to avoid polluting the global scope, you could wrap the above code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE or "iffy"). 

    `(function () {
        /* all the code above goes here */
    })()`

There are numerous slight variations of this syntax. [This is a helpful post on the subject](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would need it since the this variable will reference to the header element on both functions..
but a way you can do it is declaring the variable outside of the scope

```
var $this;

 $('header').on({
  mouseenter: function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
      },
  mouseleave: function (e) {
    $this; // is available
  },
}, 'li');
```